# Can't upgrade 11.04: flashplugin-nonfree: Package is in very bad, inconsistent state

Tags: upgrade

I can't upgrade from 11.04. I've disabled all apt sources, but still I get:

[image: Synaptics screenshot]

The only option I am capable doing is to format and reinstall whole system, which I don't prefer as I have tuned a lot of apps settings, etc.

How can I fix this?

*Update:* After restart, when trying to update all packages, I get this error:

> installArchives() failed: 
>   dpkg: error processing flashplugin-nonfree (--remove):
>    Package is in very bad, inconsistent state - before
>    trying to remove rather reinstall it.

Reinstalling it results in the same error.

*Update:*

I found a solution at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1485250 :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/flashplugin-nonfree.prerm

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq flashplugin-nonfree
sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq flashplugin-nonfree
```

But after doing that, the result is still the same.

*Update*:  Should I do what I found?  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1369723

```
for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2=="install"{print $1}'`;
  do sudo apt-get install -y --reinstall $pkg;
done
```

Comment: Seems it's time to install from a scratch...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Also, you can try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`, it's a very basic answer, but it may help.

Comment: Tried... still the same.

Comment: Maybe you should try `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2=="install" {
    system ("sudo apt-get install -y --reinstall " $1)
}`, from what I read and understand (I'm not a native English speaker) , it will reinstall all the packages, and It will take a very long time, but it's worth trying it (I read it on the link you provided).